# Problem 7 from chapter 1 ("Measure Theory") of Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis

Tags: measure-theory

The following is problem 7 from chapter 1 ("Measure Theory") of Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis.

> Consider the curve $\Gamma = \{y = f(x)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ , $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Assume that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable in $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Then show that $m(\Gamma + \Gamma) > 0$ if and only if $\Gamma + \Gamma$ contains an open set, if and only if $f$ is not linear.

---

I have proved that $\Gamma + \Gamma$ contains an open set if and only if $f$ is not linear, through the map $$\varphi\colon(a,b)\mapsto(a+b,f(a)+f(b)),$$
which is locally differential homeomorphic when $f$ is not linear.

And I also found that for given $0\leq t\leq 2$, the image of $(t,f(h)+f(t-h))$ is a line segment. Hence $\Gamma+\Gamma$ is path-connected.

But now I even do not know whether $\Gamma + \Gamma$ is measurable or not. And I do not know the why there is the condition "twice continuously differentiable".

Could you help me solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure $\varphi(a,b)$ is a differential homeomorphism?  What if $f(x)=x$ for $x \in [0,1/2]$ and we change $f$ to make it nonlinear over $x \in [1/2, 1]$? Then $\varphi$ is not bijective.

Comment: Sorry, I have not described well. More correctly, by inverse function theorem, $\varphi$ is  locally differential homeomorphic in the neighborhood of those points where $\varphi'\neq 0$. And such points always exist when $f$ is not linear. @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that  $\varphi (a,b)=(a+b,f(a)+f(b))$.

$[0,1]^2$ is compact and $\varphi$ is continuous, so $\Gamma+\Gamma=\varphi([0,1]^2)$ is also  compact.